# Where to output from large CLI app

Tags: php, separation-of-concerns, cli

I've built a reasonably sized CLI app with everything split across different classes and namespaces in a logical way. However many components need to render output from within themselves. Which seems messy.

**To expand...**

The program copies content files and databases between servers. The main file kicks in, then loads other files that handle configuration, CLI arguments, environment loading etc, then dispatches commands to other systems that do some pre-flight tests, database copying, database integrity checks, database replacements, file copying, etc.

Most of these systems have output during their operations, some use ASCII progress bars that need to be updated or otherwise output lines that need to be overwritten.

Up until now I've had each system use a dependency injected CLI Output class that wraps a bunch of output functions. But it still seems messy to trigger output from so many different systems that should only be focussing on their work task, not output.

I've experimented with creating another system that takes callbacks from all the others, then calculates and renders the output. So each subsystem is only doing the job it was assigned, but triggering callbacks with various useful information at key steps.

This is nice, but also leads to more bloat.

Is there any precedence on the best way to do this? Maybe a third way I haven't thought of?

Comment: I don't know enough about PHP to sift through the crap I find on the Internet to locate the good stuff, so I'll just tell you that what you should be doing is either providing an event that your system can subscribe to, or injecting a logger/trace object.

Comment: "So each subsystem is only doing the job it was assigned, but triggering callbacks with various useful information at key steps." - sounds good, output separated from task = opposite of "bloat" - "This is nice, but also leads to more bloat." - why? Without knowing a single line of your code, one can only guess around blindly what went wrong here. Moreover, is your *code* messy, or the *output*? Your question title imposes the 2nd, whilst your question text imposes the 1st.

Comment: Sorry, "messy" was the wrong word to use, the code is (in my bias opinion) very clean. It seems wrong to have output code spliced in with the task... but separating it out then would add a dozen more files to handle the output. So while the code will be "single concern", the relatively close aspects of task and output will be far more separated.

Comment: @Rick: first, if you do not use @ to address me, I don't get your reply in my inbox. Your comment sounds contradictory, on one hand you write your code seems to be clean, on the other, you are not satisfied with it. Without seeing any examples, we still can only guess whats wrong. My best guess is that you might be looking for how to do aspect-oriented programming in PHP. There are frameworks available for this, see, for example, [here](http://aop-php.github.io/).

Comment: @DocBrown thanks for your reply. I'm not satisfied with it because this is a pet project that I intend on continually refining over time.

I'm going to move to having all output handled by specific output classes and triggered by events in the task classes. Thanks for your help, everyone. I'm new to PHP CLI so therefore new to interactive output.

Thanks again.